# ImportError: No module named pbas

Tags: python, opencv, importerror

I'm trying to apply this openCV project from github:
https://github.com/andrewssobral/simple_vehicle_counting

I went with the python way on linux and this is the import lines i'm having trouble with:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import cv2

import analysis
import tracking
import bgs.pbas as pbas
```

The last line is the one causing this error:
[the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMCvE.png)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./build/python/demo.py", line 6, in <module>
    import bgs.pbas as pbas
  File "/home/user/Downloads/simple_vehicle_counting-master/build/python/bgs/pbas/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pbas import *
ImportError: No module named pbas
```

and the is the code inside the pbas's init file:

```
from pbas import *

# noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
import pyboostcvconverter as pbcvt
```

note: other imports like the first one `import analysis` is working fine even though the init files is very similar and this is the init file of analysis:

```
from analysis import *

# noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
import cvb
# noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
import pyboostcvconverter as pbcvt
```

Comment: That is not exactly what is inside the `__init__` for bgs.pbas when I look. i see `import _pbas`. Not sure why you have something different, but that little underscore might explain things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import doesn't look in the program's name space, so you would have to do `from bgs.pbas import *` . It doesn't know that you already imported bgs.pbas as pbas. More about where python looks for modules to import here:

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path

Comment: sorry, I did not get it 0_0. can you please explain more?
I mean why is it ok to write 'import analysis' but not 'import bgs.pbas as pbas'

Comment: @AmerAlahmar It is ok to `import bgs.pbas as pbas` . This puts bgs.pbas in the program's namespace as pbas. Import doesn't check the program's namespace though, so when you want to import * from it you need to use its full name: `from bgs.pbas import *` , not `from pbas import *` .

Comment: and what about when I need to use it? for example this line:  `segmenter = pbas.PixelBasedAdaptiveSegmenter()` should I write it like this : `segmenter = bgs.pbas.PixelBasedAdaptiveSegmenter()`, if so, what is the point of adding  "as <new name>" like this: `import bgs.pbas as pbas`
sorry for troubling you ^_^ it's just I don't like to use code that I don't understand.

Comment: @AmerAlahmar When you need to use it, you can do a few things. You could use `segmenter = pbas.PixelBasedAdaptiveSegmenter()`. Or since you did `import *` you could just use `segmenter = PixelBasedAdaptiveSegmenter()`. The first one is probably better; using `import *` is usually not recommended. You can get rid of the `from bgs.pbas import *` line since you already have pbas imported.